# Is there any way to inspect a non-active chrome tab within an extension to see the JavaScript-rendered DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, message-passing

I am trying to build a chrome extension that does web scraping in the browser instance.
I have been looking into the [chrome.devtools api](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/devtools/#:%7E:text=A%20DevTools%20extension%20adds%20functionality,devtools.) to see if I can inspect element in certain sites the block requests like Twitter or Quora. However, I am not sure if there is a programmatic way to set the context for the inspectWindow api, so I can inspect on a specific tab.

Here is what I have:
[devtools.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvjCb.png)

[background.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvBez.png)

[background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBey3.png)

I am not sure about the devtools context, It seems like it is only active when I do inspect manually. Is there a way to set it to active after opening a new tab?

Comment: Please don´t add code as images. Code in images can´t be copied and tested. Add the code as formatted text to your question.

Comment: Don't use devtools API, it's the wrong tool. Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).